# .NET 6 Setting Socket Options for MacOS

Tags: c#, .net, macos, sockets, porting

I am porting a C# .NET 4.8 app to .NET 6.0
I have the following code fragment:

```
           //Set the socket  options
        mainSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, true);

        byte[] True = new byte[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
        byte[] Out = new byte[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 }; //Capture outgoing packets

        //Socket.IOControl is analogous to the WSAIoctl method of Winsock 2
        // The current user must belong to the Administrators group on the local computer
        mainSocket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, True, Out);
```

In the last line there is IOControlCode.ReceiveAll. It displays warning:

```
CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms. IOControlCode.ReceiveAll is supported on: 'windows'.
```

Well, it means that it will not work on MacOS. What can I do to make it compatible to MacOS?

Comment: Why does you app need to receive all IPv4 packets on the network?  Is it a network analyser of some sort?

Comment: Well, it  is part of the requirement - it is looking for packets from particular source IP or particular destination IP and corresponding subnets masks.

Comment: It looks like SetSockOpt (which is what IOControl calls under the hood) is deprecated from MacOS 10.15 https://developer.apple.com/support/kernel-extensions/  There's nothing stopping you calling the macOS apis directly.   Why do you need to run this app on a Mac any way?   Why not just run it on Windows?

Comment: As I mentioned it is my client requirement to run it on MacOS...

Comment: So what do I need to call on MacOS? I am completely unfamiliar with Mac

Comment: Looks like you need to get familiar with Mac :-)  If .NET6 doesn't support promiscuous mode on Mac, then you are going to have to implement it via direct calls to Mac.   I'm guessing it's not going to be straightforward.  That being said, you are going to have a nice bit of code to submit to the .NET guys on Github.